# Chart.js added in PowerApps PCF component is not showing the tooltip properly when hover over bar chart

Tags: chart.js, powerapps, dataverse, powerapps-component-framework

We have a PowerApps which have component created using PCF. It is using Chart.j and when hovering over the bar chart, the tool tip is showing wrong data. For instance, in the screenshot, I hovered over 3/Apr/2023 but in tool tip data is showing for 7/Apr/2023
[image]

Comment: did you check if the code without being inside a PCF shows the correct tooltip or not?